# Postal code/zipcode belongs to only one street+city

Tags: sql, triggers, sql-server-2014

I have a table named ADDRESS with the following columns:

```
╔════════╦════════════╦═════════════╦════════════╗
║  City  ║   Street   ║ HouseNumber ║ PostalCode ║
╠════════╬════════════╬═════════════╬════════════╣
║        ║            ║             ║            ║
║ London ║ 1st street ║           5 ║       1234 ║
║ London ║ 1st street ║           6 ║       1234 ║
║ Stoke  ║ 1st street ║           6 ║       1235 ║
║        ║            ║             ║            ║
╚════════╩════════════╩═════════════╩════════════╝
```

I want to create a trigger that checks after an update or insert that only one city+street combination belongs to one postal code. The table above should be possible.  The example in the table below shouldn’t be possible after this trigger. So if the postalCode doesn’t yet exists the insert/update must go on. If the postcal code exits it has to check if its valid, if yes: insert/update it, if no: rollback.

I really have to keep the structure of this table, a other option isnt possible for me.

```
╔════════╦═══════════════════╦═════════════╦════════════╗
║  City  ║      Street       ║ HouseNumber ║ PostalCode ║
╠════════╬═══════════════════╬═════════════╬════════════╣
║ London ║ 1st street        ║           5 ║       1111 ║
║ London ║ 1st street        ║           6 ║       1111 ║
║ Stoke  ║ 2nd street        ║          15 ║       1111 ║
║ London ║ 1st        street ║           5 ║       1115 ║
║        ║                   ║             ║            ║
╚════════╩═══════════════════╩═════════════╩════════════╝
```

I know this table isn’t normalized properly, please don’t mind that.

Comment: Are you talking about Canadian Postal Codes?

Comment: Postal Codes, more than one way to type an address, and potential typos are a formidable combination.

Answer (score 0):

First, I am going to assume that the street column is standardized.  That is really necessary for this type of work.

I wouldn't do this using a trigger.  I would do this using another table.  For strict validation purposes, you can define:

```
create table ValidCityStreet (
    City varchar(255) not null,
    Street varchar(255) not null,
    PostalCode varchar(255),
    primary key (City, Street),  -- this ensures only one postal code
    unique (City, Street, PostalCode)  -- good for a foreign key reference
);
```

Then, add a foreign key constraint to `Address`:

```
alter table address add constraint fk_address_city_street
    foreign key (city, street) references ValidCityStreet(city, street);

alter table address add constraint fk_address_city_street_postalcode
    foreign key (city, street) references ValidCityStreet(city, street, postalcode);
```

This ensures that there is only one postal code per city/street combination (because of the primary key in `ValidCityStreet`).  And that `Address.PostalCode` matches it (because of the second foreign key reference).

That said, you will need a (simple) trigger to insert new values into `ValidCityStreet`.

Having said all that, you might consider storing the `city`/`street` pairs in a table with the postal code.  Then change the address table to refer to a row in that table, with the house number being a separate column in `Address`.

I should note that in the US a full zip-code has 9 digits.  A single address can have multiple zip codes.

Comment: Thank u for your answer! But I really have to keep the addess table like I mentioned in my post, there is no other option for me.

Comment: @user7432713 . . . Use the foreign key relationship to ensure a single postal code.